# Panoramic image movement and position sensor

Tags: android, sensors, panoramas

I'm working on android app. I have a panoramic image and I want it to move automatically depending on the position of the phone. I'm using android position sensor to give me the angle of movement. How can I implement this?? Please provide me with a code if it's possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[PanoramaGL](https://code.google.com/p/panoramagl-android/) is a very good library for displaying panoramic images.

Also you may want to checkout [this one](http://www.frank-durr.de/panodroid.html) as well